# Image not displaying when i generate invoice with TCPDF

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, tcpdf

I am trying to generate invoice in pdf using TCPDF. everything is working fine but logo image is not displaying,. here is my template code :

```
<?php
use Phppot\Order;
require_once __DIR__ . '/../Model/Order.php';
function getHTMLPurchaseDataToPDF($result, $orderItemResult, $orderedDate, $due_date)
{
ob_start();
?>
<html>
<head>Receipt of Purchase - <?php  echo $result[0]["order_invoice"]; ?>
</head>
<body>
<div><img src="logo1.jpg"  width="50" height="50"></div>
```

Comment: It probably has no idea _where_ to look for a file named `logo1.jpg`, in the context where this HTML actually gets transformed into HTML. Try and specify either a full absolute file system paths, or an absolute URL.

Comment: i placed html file and image in same folder. with dompdf its work absolutly fine but with tcpdf its not displaying

Comment: What "html file"? You have a _script_ generating HTML output here. And we can't currently see, in which context that output will be used later.